# Loop 'svc wifi enable' until wifi is on with Android terminal

Tags: android, loops, while-loop, terminal, wifi

First question on stackoverflow
So I got a huawei android phone
With a bad wifi 
I should turn on the wifi ≈20 times (from the notification control) so it can turns on
So I've made a sh file (contains svc wifi enable) and execute it with terminal 
But I have to run that file for 10 times so the wifi can be enabled 
Tried this 
`for i in seq 1 50; do sh on $i; done`
('on' is a file that contains 'svc enable wifi') 
But same thing I have to run it many times
So
I just wanted to make a terminal command with the **while** loop
I mean:
While (wifi is disconnected) do (svc wifi enable) until (wifi is connected)
But I don't know how
So I'm asking for your help
Thanks for reading this ❤️

Answer (score 0):

You should check the `ping` command. Try `ping -c 1 google.com && break` in the loop. It should then exit the loop when it gets internet connectivity. You should probably put a `sleep` statement to avoid spamming the system.